# Get unread messages from array with all email messages in Java

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write a method that gets an array of unread mail messages from an array with all messages. This is my code:

```
public Message[] getUnreadMessages() {
    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(1, messageCount);
    Message[] unreadMessages;
    int i = 0;
    for (Message message : messages) {
        boolean isMessageRead = false;
        for (Flags.Flag flag : message.getFlags().getSystemFlags()) {
            if (flag == Flags.Flag.SEEN) {
                isMessageRead = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        String subject = message.getSubject();
        if (isMessageRead) {
            log.debug("Message with subject '" + subject + "' has status read");
        } else {
            unreadMessages[i] = new Message();
            unreadMessages[i] = message;
            i++;
            log.info("Message with subject '" + subject + "' will be processed");
        }
    }
    return unreadMessages;
}
```

However, this doesn't work because I cannot instantiate a new Message() type. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you even do that `unreadMessages[i] = new Message();` if on the next line you do `unreadMessages[i] = message;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set:

```
unreadMessages[i] = message;
```

The line before is useless, because you just overwrite the pointer one line deeper (Some IDE will say this)

One more suggestion:

Make unreadMessages a `List<Message>` you can add a `Message` withiout calculating `i`

```
public Message[] getUnreadMessages() {
    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(1, messageCount);
    List<Message> readMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        boolean isMessageRead = false;
        for (Flags.Flag flag : message.getFlags().getSystemFlags()) {
            if (flag == Flags.Flag.SEEN) {
                readMessages.add(message);
                break;
            }
        }
    List<Message> unread = Arrays.asList(messages).removeAll(readMessagess); 
    return unread .toArray(new Message[unread.size()]);
}
```

Comment: It might be even better if the signature can be changed to return a list, but that might not be possible for other reasons.

Comment: Great code, lots of help. One thing, you are adding the messages to the unreadMessages now when it has the Flag SEEN. That is quite the opposite, as these are the readMessages. So I am sticking to setting a boolean isMessageRead to true and using that to populate the list.

Comment: Ohh ... did not see this. Will change it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the line that puts a new message into the array. The next line just overrides that slot in the array anyway.